# Nginx doesn't always handle proxy_pass requests

Tags: vue.js, nginx, proxypass

I have an app in docker-compose with a Vue.js frontend in Nginx and a backend. In the Nginx configuration, I have two proxies: one for requests to the backend and another for the file server (i use yandex cloud s3 storage). The purpose of proxying to the backend is to bypass restrictions on requests to the HTTP host, while proxying to the file server is done to bypass the same-origin restriction of the download attribute.

On the frontend, there is a button that opens several links with the download attribute to download files from the file server via the proxied link (localhost/download/filename.mp4 instead of example.com/filename.mp4). However, when the button is pressed, instead of downloading, for example, 10 files, only a few are downloaded, and the rest show "Network error". In the Nginx logs, it is evident that out of 10 requests, only 1-2 are handled.

My nginx configuration

```
events {
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl on;
        server_name https://localhost;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain-demo.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/pk-demo.key;
        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location /api/ {
          proxy_pass http://backend:8080/;
        }
        location /download/ {
          proxy_pass https://example.com/;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name localhost;

        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

I tested the frontend when downloading files outside of nginx and docker-compose with downloading local files and everything worked fine.

What could be causing this issue and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem could stem from a number of factors, including a browser restriction, a Nginx configuration error, or a problem with the backend/file server. Let's consider a few options:

Limitations of browsers: Browsers frequently set a limit on the number of connections that can be made to a single domain at once. In Chrome, six connections are permitted per domain. Due to this restriction, some files may not download if you attempt to download more than six files simultaneously from the same domain.

The number of simultaneous connections or requests may be restricted by your Nginx setup. Search for directives like worker_connections, worker_processes, and keepalive_timeout in your Nginx configuration file.

Limitations on your file server's backend or the quantity of concurrent connections or requests could potentially be the cause of some of the download requests failing. If at all feasible, look for more details about the reasons the requests are failing in the file server logs or the backend logs.

You can attempt the following to lessen the problem:

If the problem is browser-related, stagger the download requests to prevent exceeding the limit. This might be done by programming your download button to start each consecutive download a little bit later than the one before it.

If the problem is with Nginx, try raising the worker_connections and worker_processes limits to handle more simultaneous requests. Increase keepalive_timeout as well to prevent premature connection closure.

Change backend/file server settings: You might need to change the settings for the backend or the file server to permit more simultaneous connections or requests if those are the sources of the problem. Depending on the software or service you're using, the specific procedure will vary.

Investigate network problems: The issue could be brought on by a network fault. To check if there are any obvious network difficulties, use programs like traceroute, ping, and mtr.

While troubleshooting and adjusting, keep an eye on how the system is using its resources (CPU, memory, network, etc.). By doing this, you'll assist avoid overtaxing the system while trying to fix the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT